# CSS div with text as mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve a mask-type effect with a coloured div's large text in HTML. I want this masked text to show parts of an image which is behind the div. However; instead of using the `background-clip` property and a `background-image` on the div itself - I am hoping to simply reveal what ever is underneath the element (in my case, the image).
I have tried using svg images with compound paths, they proved too difficult to handle.
Is there ANY other way I could do this? CSS? jQuery plugin?
[image: A not-so-successful attempt with svg]

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Comment: I have seen this, helpful - but not what I'm looking for. I need the text to simply reveal what's underneath it. Not looking to give a background image.

Comment: How else would there be an image underneath it?

Comment: The div is floating over images, and the reason I don't just use the background image is that I will be animating it - which will complicate things further.

Comment: @grevin Depending on exactly how you will use it, there may be a workaround or a hack, but with only the information you've provided so far, there is no solution.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to [my website](http://gablescode.com)? The input boxes are transparent.

Comment: Not really @Luxelin, but that looks awesome! I'll see if I can find a working example.

Comment: Okay thanks @Shiazure, fair enough :)

Comment: @grevin I'd like to amend my statement, it's possible with canvas, as bostaunieux had shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this article for applying a text mask](http://blog.ericzhang.com/punch-through-text-masks-with-css-and-html5/), you could do this with a canvas tag.

```
<div id="bg"><canvas id="overlay" width="240" height="70"></canvas></div>
<script>
// Get a handle to our canvas
var ctx = document.getElementById('overlay').getContext("2d");

// Choose font
ctx.font = "Bold 36px 'Helvetica'";

// Draw black rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = "black"; 
ctx.fillRect(0,0,230,70); 

// Punch out the text!
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'; 
ctx.fillText("Some Text", 25, 50);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6aVGU/

Comment: This looks promising, thanks! Is it possible to then animate the height of that black box within the canvas?

Comment: please consider using d3, the best JavaScript graphics library available

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the Canvas object:
http://jsfiddle.net/JackKalish/g3BDa/3/

```
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var canvasContext1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

    // destination-out 
    // Text cuts-out everything under it
    // background is revealed in the cut-out
    makeGradientAndFont(canvasContext1, canvas1);
    canvasContext1.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    canvasContext1.fillText("Portfolio", 175, 50);

    function makeGradientAndFont(ctx, canvas) {
        var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        grad.addColorStop(0, '#0000FF');
        grad.addColorStop(.3, '#00FFFF');
        grad.addColorStop(.4, '#99FFFF');
        grad.addColorStop(.5, '#00FF00');
        grad.addColorStop(.6, '#FFFF00');
        grad.addColorStop(.8, '#F00000');
        ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = grad;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.font = "55px Arial";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This also looks similar what I was hoping for :)

Answer (score -2):

You could do this with a transparent PNG image of the text.

Comment: I guess I will do this if I can't find anything else - but I was hoping for a solution which would allow me to easily edit the text :) Thanks.